# Search for a spesific userID in Firebase with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm kind of new with Firebase, I tried with firebase doc but i couldn't handle it. I want to query for specific currentUserID in "locations", if there is no currentUserID, then I want to create a child for current user. How can I do that?

// I tried this and it didn't work.

```
  dataRef.child("locations").child(id).observe(.value, with: { (refIDSnapshot) in
        guard let dicID = refIDSnapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
            return 
        }

        if dicID.isEmpty {
            dataRef.child("locations").child(id).setValue(locValues)
        }
    })
```

// I also tried this

```
dataRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "locations").queryEqual(toValue: id).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            guard let dic1 = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else {
                return
            }
                    if dic1.isEmpty {
        dataRef.child("locations").child(id).setValue(locValues)
    }
```

//Firebase Database Structure

```
"ProjectName":{
  "locations":{
    "hVfS9EU6LWatAynJNepayDmum4A2":{
       "-KZCxgfgBjEOusuo-Fay":{
          "longitude":"22.12431412",
          "latitude":"13.23423423"
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: // This worked for me

```
dataRef.child("locations").child(id).observe(.value, with: { (refIDSnapshot) in
        let dicID = refIDSnapshot.value as? [String: Any]

        if dicID == nil {
            dataRef.child("locations").child(id).childByAutoId().setValue(locValues)
        }

    })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can read up on how to [ask] a question and create a [mcve]. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @Katie Thank you for suggestions. :)

Comment: Please don't use a return within a Firebase closure. Firebase is asynchronous so Firebase functions should not be called like regular synchronous functions that return a value. The code within the closure will execute once Firebase returns with the data, and only then should be data be used. Using a return could quite possibly cause a rift in the space-time continuum. Also, please post your Firebase structure as text, not an image so its searchable and makes it so we don't have to retype it when we answer.